# PDFTK: combining files as root user

Tags: server, permissions, pdf, pdftk

I have a website which uses PDFTK.

My site allows users to send PDF files via a form, then, at the click of a button, launches a combination of all files to create one.

When sending my files, my apache user is assigned.

Except that when I run the command line, it does not work. If I pass all my files in user and group root, the command line is passed. Except that I have a manual action to do what is not possible for the proper functioning of my site.

This is my command with the error:

```
$ /snap/bin/pdftk "upload/418/2018/fichier1.pdf" cat output upload/418/2018/fichiercombine.pdf dont_ask
Error: Unable to find file.
Error: Failed to open PDF file:
   upload/418/2018/fichier1.pdf
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
```

This is a good command but with `chown`:

```
chown -R root:root upload/418/2018
/snap/bin/pdftk "upload/418/2018/fichier1.pdf" cat output upload/418/2018/fichiercombine.pdf dont_ask
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

This command that works according to you:

```
chown -R root:root upload/418/2018
/snap/bin/pdftk "upload/418/2018/fichier1.pdf" cat output upload/418/2018/fichiercombine.pdf dont_ask
```

was preceeded by a change directory (something like `cd /var/www/html/`).

This one did not do that:

```
$ /snap/bin/pdftk "upload/418/2018/fichier1.pdf" cat output upload/418/2018/fichiercombine.pdf dont_ask
Error: Unable to find file.
Error: Failed to open PDF file:
   upload/418/2018/fichier1.pdf
Errors encountered.  No output created.
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
```

... so will try to execute it from inside a directory that does start where you put `upload/` The notice does not complain about permissions so I would assume that is not the problem. It says "file not found" instead so I believe your 2nd command is not executed at the correct directory. If it is though a permission issue: add the user apache to the group that owns `pdftk` or, if that is owned by root, change the group for that to a new group and add apache to it.

If it is a directory issuue the asiest fix would be to use absolute paths and not relative paths. Or add a `cd /var/www/html &&` in front of the command where you replace the `/var/www/html` for what it needs to be.